# How to start my application activity from Test App in android

Tags: android

I have developed one application.I have around 10 activities in my application.for some of the activities there are no intent filters.

Now i want to write a Test App in that i want to mention 10 buttons and when i press on each button i want to start my application activity.

Test App is for only testing my activity UI is proper or not.generally we will do through the running adb shell am start -n "activity" command.But i need ti launch application.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Create 10 intents for each of your activities using their package names. Check out [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) for more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: Intent inten = new Intent();
    inten.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.exampleactivity",".FirstActivity"));
    startActivity(inten);                        I am using above code..but I am getting ActivityNot found exception

Comment: Is your FirstActivity in `com.example.exampleactivity` package? Then use  
`intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.exampleactivity","com.example.exampleactivity.FirstActivity"));`

Comment: Intent inten = new Intent(); inten.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.exampleactivity","com.example.exampleactivity.FirstActivity")); startActivity(inten);       with this also i am getting ActivityNotFOund exception